# GNU makefile to "overlay one source list" overtop of "another source list"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have two source directories...

one directory has automatically generated code.
The other directory has code that takes the automatically generated code and adds customizations to the code...

I want to merge these two source directories automatically such that the `basename` of the source path for each file replaces the `basename in the automatically generated source directory.  Example:

```
SRC_AUTO := $(wildcard path1/path2/src_auto/*.cpp)
SRC_WORK := $(wildcard path3/path4/src_work/*.cpp)

# How to achieve this with GNU Make without going out to $shell or perl...
SRC_MERGED := overlay_basename($SRC_WORK, $SRC_AUTO)
```

Example:

```
SRC_AUTO := \
    ./path1/path2/src_auto/pathz/file1.cpp \
    ./path1/path2/src_auto/pathx/pathy/file2.cpp \
    ./path1/path2/src_auto/file3.cpp

SRC_WORK := \
    ./path3/path4/src_work/file1.cpp \
    ./path3/path4/src_work/file3.cpp

#This is what I need to generate automatically
SRC_MERGED := \
   path1/path2/src_auto/pathx/pathy/file2.cpp \
   path3/path4/src_work/file1.cpp \
   path3/path4/src_work/file3.cpp
```

except with more files... SRC_WORK overlays SRC_AUTO keyed off of the basename of the filepath.

Here's what I basically want to do from GNU make in perl pseudo-code:

```
@SRC_AUTO = ( ...list of automatically generated files.. );
@SRC_WORK = ( ...list of customized files copied from auto directory );

%unique = ();
foreach $file (@SRC_WORK) {
    $base = basename($file);
    $unique{$base} = $file;
}

foreach $file (@SRC_AUTO) {
    $base = basename($file);
    if (!defined($unique{$base}) {
         $unique{$base} = $file;            
    }
}
@merged_list = ();
foreach $key (keys %unique) {
    $file = $unique{$key};
    push(@merged_list, $file);
}
@sorted_merged_list = sort(@merged_list);

return @sorted_merged_list;
```

Update, After some more refinement, I now have the perl script below:  (now if only you could do this auto-matically from gnu make with a single built-in function without a breaky script environment of scripts that call scripts..):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Automatically Generated Source Code
$dir_auto   = "../src_auto";

# Overlayed Source Code
$dir_work   = "../src_work";

#Merge File Output
$merge_list = "source.txt";

use File::Find;

sub OverlaySource($$) 
{
    my $dir_auto = shift;
    my $dir_work = shift;

    my %unique = ();

    my @cpp_work;
    find( sub {
        my $file = $_;
        if ($file =~ /\.cpp$/) {
            $path = $dir_work . "/" . $file;
            $unique{$file} = $path;
        }
    }, $dir_work);

    my @cpp_auto;
    find( sub {
        my $file = $_;
        return if (defined($unique{$file}));
        if ($file =~ /\.cpp$/) {
            $path = $dir_auto . "/" . $file;
            $unique{$file} = $path;         
        }
    }, $dir_auto);

    my @tmp = ();
    foreach $key (keys %unique) {
        $file = $unique{$key};
        push(@tmp, $file);
    }

    my @cpp_files = sort @tmp;
    return @cpp_files;
}


$dir_auto = "../src_auto";
$dir_work = "../src_work";

my @cpp_files = OverlaySource($dir_auto, $dir_work);

print "Creating File: $merge_list\n";
open(F, ">${merge_list}"); 
foreach $file (@cpp_files) {
    print F "$file\n";
}
close(F);
```

Comment: Could you tell us what you're trying to do, rather than asking us to reverse-engineer your Perl script? Perhaps show a couple of file names (with paths), and then the list you want to create (if you want to create a list-- I really can't tell).

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
SRC_MERGED := $(filter-out $(addprefix %/,$(notdir $(SRC_WORK))),$(SRC_AUTO)) $(SRC_WORK)
```

Explanation:

1. `$(notdir $(SRC_WORK))` returns the base names of all words in `$(SRC_WORK)`: `file1.cpp file3.cpp`.
2. `$(addprefix %/,$(notdir $(SRC_WORK)))` adds the `%/` prefix to the result of 1; this is a list of make patterns (`%` is the wildcard): `%/file1.cpp %/file3.cpp`.
3. `$(filter-out $(addprefix %/,$(notdir $(SRC_WORK))),$(SRC_AUTO))` returns all words in `$(SRC_AUTO)` that do not match any pattern in `$(addprefix %/,$(notdir $(SRC_WORK)))`: `./path1/path2/src_auto/pathx/pathy/file2.cpp`.
4. `$(filter-out $(addprefix %/,$(notdir $(SRC_WORK))),$(SRC_AUTO)) $(SRC_WORK)` just concatenates `$(SRC_WORK)` to the result of 3:

   ```
   ./path1/path2/src_auto/pathx/pathy/file2.cpp ./path3/path4/src_work/file1.cpp ./path3/path4/src_work/file3.cpp
   ```